# Fibonacci sequence: Prove the formula $f_{2n+1}=f_{n+1}^2 + f_n^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, fibonacci-numbers

I can't seem to figure out this proof. I'm using weak induction and always get stuck during the inductive step.

Prove for n > 0: 
$$f_{2n+1} = f_{n+1}^2 + f_n^2$$

Comment: Hi. [See this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for info about writing mathematical formulas on this site (and you can also press edit on questions to see how the formulas have been written).

Comment: Are you required to use weak induction for this exercise?  Have you tried using strong induction?

Comment: The formula is derived [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form)

Comment: Besides the obvious proof by induction, this can also be proved using the explicit formula for the Fibonacci sequence.